# Can I change my Pokémon's attacks?

Tags: pokemon-go

Can I change my Pokémon's attacks or are they random and unchangeable? If a it has more powerful moves before it evolves, does it have higher chance to get powerful moves after it evolves?

Answer (score 9):

In latest update that incorporated raids, you are now able to change the attacks your Pokémon has through TMs and Charged TMs, which will teach your Pokémon a random new move. These items are rewards for defeating the raid boss

[Niantic Support](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/115009004687-What-s-changing-in-Pok%C3%A9mon-GO-)

> **Fast TM**
>
> This Technical Machine item is used to teach your Pokémon a new Fast Attack. Your Pokémon will acquire a new Fast Attack and forget their old Fast Attack.
>
> **Charged TM**
>
> This item works like the Fast TM but it teaches the Charged Attack instead of a Fast Attack. Remember, the Charged Attack is performed by pressing and holding during battle.

Answer (score 3):

You can not change your pokemon attack. It is random. However during evolution the attacks do change but they too are random!

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Pokémon Go resource](http://serebii.net/pokemongo/moves.shtml):

> "...the moves that your Pokémon have are unable to be changed, leaving
>   you with the set moves that you have when you get the Pokémon,
>   although some will change through evolution."

So, you cannot change your Pokémon's attacks, and evolving your Pokémon generates a new set of random attacks. If you want to ensure you get the best attacks, I suggest saving up candies to evolve several Pokémon of the same type and compare their attacks.

The source linked above also gives a list of *Fast Attacks* and *Special Attacks* that shows the damage, critical hit chance, duration, energy requirements, etc. of each move. This chart may be useful in deciding which Pokémon to keep.

**EDIT**

[This site](https://thesilphroad.com/research) has a better, easier to read layout for each Pokémon's moves. However, with the new update, many moves have been changed. For example, Vaporeon's extremely powerful moves have been nerfed. [This resource](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiqVp.jpg) shows the changes made to each move.